# Which word is more appropriate in this headline: “captivate” or “engross”?

Tags: word-choice

Consider this headline:

> Horrific Accident On Live TV Captivates The Internet

Dictionary.com gives the following definitions for *captivate*:

> 1. to attract and hold the attention or interest of, as by beauty or excellence; enchant.
> 2. Obsolete . to capture; subjugate.

and the following for *engross*:

> 1. to occupy completely, as the mind or attention; absorb.
> 2. to write or copy in a clear, attractive, large script or in a formal manner, as a public document or record.
> 3. to acquire the whole of (a commodity), in order to control the market; monopolize.

It seems to me “engross” is more appropriate.

Are there other verbs that better suit this context?

Answer (score 2):

I feel that both *captivate* and *engross* imply a subject of a pleasant nature. I would be *captivated by the beautiful dawn* and can get *engrossed in a good book*.

The dictionary definition you have provided for *captivate* supports this since it mentions "beauty or excellence". I would use neither word to describe the obsession over horrific events that can affect people.

Additionally, the internet is a loose collection of computers communicating via certain protocols. It can be neither captivated nor engrossed. The people using it can be, but not the internet itself. For the specific usage of your question, I would say:

> Horrific Accident On Live TV Sets The Internet Abuzz

or

> Horrific Accident On Live TV Is All Over The Internet

or

> Horrific Accident On Live TV Floods The Internet

If you can change the word order, this would be even better:

> Internet Abuzz Over Horrific Accident On Live TV

Now, if you really really need to use to stick to the form of your original question, I would either go for *grips* as @KristinaLopez suggested or [*fascinates*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fascinate) which has neither positive nor negative connotations and is often used in both contexts:

> Horrific Accident On Live TV Fascinates The Internet

Comment: I'm going for this one because at least you've pointed out that both *captivate* and *engross* aren't really appropriate descriptors for a "horrific accident" (they usually imply *entertain, thrill, enthral, enchant, bedazzle*, etc.). *Fascinate* has quite a bit going for it though, bearing in mind ***morbid** fascination* is a commonplace conjunction. Whatever, I still think the question itself is POB.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, @terdon, but I can't agree that captivate and engross imply a pleasant nature.  There's nothing other then our own opinion or sentiment to fuel that argument.  There is a dark side to attraction, substantiated by some of captivate's synonyms: beguile, bewitch, fascinate, magnetize, wile.  And related words: disarm, draw, entice, lure, pull, seduce, tempt, interest, intrigue; beckon, court, invite, solicit, woo

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one of the words in the definition of ***"captivate"*** makes it my preferred word - ***"attract"***.  If the story does not attract someone's attention, there is no possibility for them to get "engrossed" in it.

For another option, there is ***"[mesmerize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mesmerize)"***:

> 1) to subject to mesmerism; also : hypnotize
>
> 2) spellbind
>
> Synonyms: arrest, bedazzle, catch up, enchant, fascinate, grip,
>   hypnotize, enthrall, spellbind

One of the related words, ***"grip"***, is also good for your purpose:

> News of the horrific accident ***gripped*** the Internet

Comment: @ Kristina Lopezto attract as of by beauty or excellence it is mentioned. How can a horrific event do?

Comment: Not attraction as in sexual attraction but in the sense of "fascination".  We all look at the accident on the side of the road because we have a lurid fascination with disasters and misfortunes of others. I guess another way to look at the word "attract" is like a moth is "attracted" to a light.  It can't resist flying into it - not because it loves it but because it can't help it.

Comment: I would opt for this word only if the language was running short for words. But English does offer - what seems to me- a better alternative. Perhaps it's a personal matter, I'm not comfortable with the word 'captivate' in this particular context.

Comment: Fortunately there are plenty of synonyms out there for both those words. Mesmerize has a certain appeal.  I'm appending my answer to include it and its synonyms.

Comment: I wasn't very sure about "engross" either--that's why I asked for other synonyms that carry the right connotation.

Answer (score 0):

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/engross) has pithier definitions for these words that may help clarify their use.

> **captivate**, *v.t.*: to attract or interest someone very much
>
> **engross**, *v.t.*: when something engrosses you, you think about nothing else

So *captivate* is entirely appropriate in the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Horrific accident on live TV goes viral.
I think everybody gets this shorthand - and it makes for a snappier, more authoritative headline.
If a word is tripping you up in a heading, look for a different construction.